# "Lunch" vs "luncheon"

Tags: differences, american-english, british-english

What is the difference between *lunch* and *luncheon*? Is it just American spelling vs British spelling, or do they have some sort of formal/professional touch to them, say, a casual midday meal with friends is called *lunch* while that with your colleagues/business clients is called *luncheon*?

Comment: Yes, though "luncheon" would be considered rather posh by today's standards. It's practically an archaic term in most areas of England.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Precisely.

> **luncheon**: a light meal *of more formal character* usually for a group of people in a public dining room (as at a club meeting or a
>   business meeting)
>
> **lunch**: **a**: a light meal usually in the middle of the day : LUNCHEON **b** : a light meal taken at any time of the day or night at
>   a selected place
>
> [Merriam-Webster Unabridged]

Comment: source, pl.? (I could Google backwards, though.)

Comment: Also, you can "have lunch" but not "have luncheon"; "luncheon" takes a determiner.

Comment: Why does the definition of lunch have a different definition of luncheon than the actual entry for luncheon? Is that just an editing mistake ?